# Whenever I open integrated terminal in VS code 1.18, it crashes PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Even though I have set below code in setting.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Whenever I open the "integrated terminal" it starts and right away shows:

```
"The terminal process terminated with exit code: 259"
```

There is also a dialog outside code saying:

```
"powershell has stopped working
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. 
Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."
```

this happens in 32bit and 64bit too

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you open bash from a PowerShell terminal?

Comment: I get "The term 'bash' is not recognized as" Do I need to install bash?

Comment: Found it seems a few folks have reported this issue with Code in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36994). You might post your details there so they know more folks are having the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code 259 usually means STILL_ACTIVE and this is rather strange.
You may try to use ProcessMonitor to determine which processes are started during your call and perhaps that gives you a clue.

Open Task Manager
I Clicked on End Task on all process of VS Code

Error vanished